# Fit a regression line with categorical variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have simulated a dataset and stored it in a tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2002)
tre.sett <- rnorm(n = 12, mean = 41, sd = 5) #12 individer
ett.sett <-rnorm(n = 12, mean = 21, sd = 5) #12 individer

dat <- tibble(individ = seq(1:24),
              gruppe = rep(c("tre.sett", "ett.sett"), c(length(tre.sett), length(ett.sett))),
              rm = c(tre.sett, ett.sett))
```

Next I can create a basic plot of **rm** and **gruppe** using ggplot from tidyverse.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(gruppe, rm)) +
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()
```

This gives me the following figure:

[image]

I want to add a regresson line between the two groups, but I'm struggling to implement one. If I use geom_smooth() nothing appears in figure. The intercept and slope from my model is 21.900 and  20.524, respectively.

Comment: Those values are not the intercept and slope of your model, the value 21.900 is the mean value at the factor gruppe base level `"ett.sett"` and 20.524 is the increment from that level to `"tre.sett"`.

Comment: As for the regression line, try it with `ggplot(dat, aes(as.integer(factor(gruppe)), rm))` and `geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, se = FALSE)`.

Comment: Factors are discrete, i.e. there are no values between these two levels. Thus a regression line is not a sensible concept here.

Comment: Thank you, Rue. It worked! I don't understand why I can't say that they are the intercept and slope of my model. Arguably, they are when I have dummy coded my variable. I assume no inherent ordering among the levels of the variable. The interpretation of the intercept is the estimated mean for the group coded as zero; β1 can be interpreted as the difference between the mean for the baseline group and the group coded as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution has been given in the comments: re-encode the categories as integers before using `geom_smooth`.

Another solution. Since the "regression line" just connects the mean of the two groups, you can use `stat_summary`:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gruppe, rm)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, group = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

You might also want to look at the [sjPlot package](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/) which uses the `plot_model` function to visualise regression models. It would be used something like this:

```
library(sjPlot)
lm1 <- lm(rm ~ gruppe, data = dat)
lm1 %>% 
  plot_model(type = "pred", 
             terms = "gruppe", 
             show.data = TRUE) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]